# Pass a captured named regular expression to URL dictionary in generic view

Tags: django-urls

I am working with a generic view in Django.  I want to capture a named group parameter in the URL and pass the value to the URL pattern dictionary.  For example, in the URLConf below, I want to capture the `parent_slug` value in the URL and pass it to the queryset dictionary value like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    (r'^(?P<parent_slug>[-\w]+)$',
     'object_list',
     {'queryset':Promotion.objects.filter(category=parent_slug)},
     'promo_promotion_list',
    ),
                      )
```

Is this possible to do in one URLConf entry, or would it be wiser if I create a custom view to capture the value and pass the queryset directly to the generic view from my overridden view?

Comment: Investigating a similar requirement myself - I'll let you know if I find anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing some redirects in urls.py as follows, maybe that works for you too?

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^manual/glossary/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$',
        RedirectView.as_view(url='/glossary/%(slug)s/')),
)
```

However, that seems not to be supported by all class based generic views:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^tag/(?P<tag>\d+)/$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Blog.Post.objects.filter(tags='%(tag)d'),
            paginate_by=5)),
)
```

This second code snipplet does not work, so you would have to patch the generic ListView or pass via a custom view as you proposed.